# Using ASP.NET how can I create a zip file from an array of strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, zip

I am using ASP.NET and I prefer VB as the language, but I should be able to translate C# for my needs.

I have an array of strings which I would like to send to the browser as individual files for the user to save. In searching the internet, the most common solution to send multiple files to a browser is to zip them up, and send a single zip file.

Towards that end, I need to learn a few things I do not know;

1) What tool/methods (preferably built in to ASP.NET running on IIS7) can I use to create a zip filestream to send to a browser?

2) How do I fool the zip tool into thinking it is getting multiple files from strings in memory? I assume I need to create filestreams, but how do I tell the methods what the file name is, etc.?

If there is an example of doing something substantially similar to what I need available, that would be great. Just point me at it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: that's strange.  Why don't you just send one XML file

Comment: I don't think you have done any extensive research (if any research at all) on the subject... The basic logic I would try is 1) write the files as physically existing (temporary) files 2) zip them together 3) return the zip file to the client as a filestream 4) delete all the files including the zip. You can quite easilly find explanations on all these steps on the Web, and come back here with some code whenever you get stuck.

Comment: I would agree that I have not done "extensive" research. I did some, but I wanted to keep everything "diskless" if possible.

Comment: Jonesy, the task requires retrieving hundreds of thousands of rows from a DB query, splitting it up into delimited files of no more than n lines.

Comment: Voting to keep open, solution did not involve a tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach could be:

1. Convert the string into stream
2. Add data from that stream into the zip file
3. Write the zip file into response stream

Code example below:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();
int fileNumber = 1;

foreach(string str in strArray)
{
    // convert string to stream
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    //add the string into zip file with a name
    zipFile.AddEntry("String" + fileNumber.ToString() + ".txt", "", stream);
}

Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=strings.zip");

zipFile.Save(Response.OutputStream);
zipFile.Dispose();
```

Comment: Manish, I am in the process of implementing this. It looks like exactly what I need thanks for your help.